# How to configure nginx to redirect subdomain to another directory

Tags: nginx, webserver, nginx-config

I have an application that I wish that once I access my subdomain portfolio.jamelaumn.com to be redirected to my localhost/portfolio how would I achieve that?

my configuration;

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name jamelaumn.com *.jamelaumn.com;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name jamelaumn.com *.jamelaumn.com;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/jamelaumn.com-0001/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/jamelaumn.com-0001/privkey.pem;


    location /static/ {
        alias /home/jamelaumn/myproject/deploystatic/;
    }

    location /media/ {
        alias /home/jamelaumn/myproject/media/;
    }
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "redirected to my localhost/portfolio"? Where does this get served? Under `jamelaumn.com/portfolio`? Or under `jamelaumn.com`? So you want to get redirected from `portfolio.jamelaumn.com` to e.g. `jamelaumn.com/portfolio`?

Comment: yes, something like that, im new on webservers so I don't know the correct terms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name portfolio.jamelaumn.com; # So this server block handles that subdomain
  return 301 https://jamelaumn.com/portfolio$request_uri; # Redirect to your main domain with the subdirectory portfolio
}
```

You can also redirect it, if someone requests with https, you just need a valid ssl cert for that:

```
server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name portfolio.jamelaumn.com; # So this server block handles that subdomain
  
  # SSL Configuration
  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/jamelaumn.com-0001/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/jamelaumn.com-0001/privkey.pem;
  
  return 301 https://jamelaumn.com/portfolio$request_uri; # Redirect to your main domain with the subdirectory portfolio
}
```

Comment: right so I would need to have more ports? to handle the normal "domain jamelaumn.com", while the answer you game me might be handling the subdomain it stopped handling the domain sou I just need to listen to more ports?

Comment: No you dont have to listen on more ports. You can listen on the same block and handle the response with the sent host name (`server_name`). If your main domain stopped working you might need to have a look at the nginx logs. So you are getting redirected from the `portfolio` subdomain to your main domain, but nothing gets served there?